# calling python function

Tags: python, function, lambda

Below is an example of using lambda functions within a user-defined function:

```
def sample_func(a):       #1
    return lambda a:a*a
```

When this is called,

```
s=sample_func(2)          #2
print(s)
```

Output seems to be a function address like `<function sample_func.<locals>.<lambda> at 0000xx`

And after the above assignment to variable `s`, the below

```
s(5)                      #3
```

returns 25.

New here to python lambda, what is the correct way to interpret this and how does the interpreter treat the argument in #2 and why 4 is not returned in #2, thank you for the help!

Comment: `sample_func` returns a function, so `s` is a function. Like any function, you have to call it if you want to use it. Also, the lambda function has one parameter, so you have to call it with an argument. Note that this argument is completely unrelated to the `a` in `sample_func(a)`, which is just ignored.

Comment: A `lambda` is a  function. `sample_func` returns a lambda function, so `#2` gives you that output. You assign that function to `s`, and then call it in `#3` with an argument `5`. Your function takes that and returns `5*5`. The argument `(2)` in `#2` goes into `a` when you call `sample_func`, but nothing is done with it. `a` in the `lambda` function refers to the `a` argument of the lambda. What are you confused about?

Comment: Thanks @PranavHosangadi, yes as to how it needs to be interpreted that `2 goes into a, but nothing is done with it` as you have mentioned

Comment: If you named your lambda's argument something else: for example, see what you get when you `return lambda x: a * x`. When you name it `a` and there's already a variable in that scope called `a`, the lambda's `a` hides `sample_func`'s `a`

Comment: Perfect @PranavHosangadi, answers it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a bit of trickery going on here because the variable `a` is used several times.

First thing though, what you are doing in #2 is calling `some_func`, which returns a function object. A lambda is a function object, which in your case you are assigning to `s`. In #3 you are calling that function and passing in the value 5. At that point `s` is basically equivalent to:

```py
def s(foo: int):
    return foo * foo
```

Let's take a closer look at this function:

```py
def sample_func(a):       #1
    return lambda a:a*a
```

When you call `sample_func()`, it returns a function object. This returned function takes in an argument `a` and returns `a*a`. So what is happening is the argument `a` that is passed into `sample_func()` is basically never used. If you are wondering why, it has to do with how Scope works in Python. Take this following code as an easier to understand example:

```py
1) def outer_function(foo: int):
2)     print("Currently in outer_function, and foo is " + foo)
3)     
4)     def inner_function(foo: int):
5)         print("Currently in inner_function and foo is " + foo)
6)     return inner_function
```

In the above code, the `foo` variable on line 5 refers to the `foo` argument passed into `inner_function()`, it doesn't refer back to the `foo` argument of `outer_function`. You can think of `inner_function()` as your lambda.

Hopefully that all makes sense!

Comment: Thanks @Zach Munro, the inner and outer function soo clearly explains the variable scopes, thanks much, upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

`sample_func` is a function factory, in the sense that it returns functions (in this case lambda functions).

So the return value of `sample_func` is a function itself. Thus, when you store it in #2 in a variable, you store the lambda function there. It is equivalent to:

```
s = lambda x: x*x
```

Then when you call the function s(5), it uses x=5, and returns 5*5=25. Similarly, s(4), uses x=4, and returns 4*4=16.

In a more general sense, `lambda *args: return_value`.

In this case, the parameter `a` of `sammple_func` is unused, since we redeclare it inside the lambda.

```
def sample_func(a):       #1
    return lambda a: a*a
```

is equivalent to:

```
def sample_func(_):       #1
        return lambda a: a*a
```

If you wanted to access the `a` from `sample_func` inside the lambda, simply call the lambda's argument something else:

```
def sample_func(a):
    return lambda x: a * x
```

Now if you ran your code, `s(5)` would return `10`, which is equal to `2 * 5`

Comment: Thanks @miquelvir, could you please explain the significance of 2 in `s=sample_func(2) `, because only after this assignment when we call s(4), it returns 16

Comment: Forget about the lambda, your function is basically `def s(x): return x*x`, nothing else. So, of course `s(4)` returns `16`.

Comment: sure, done! if that solves your issue mark it as such please

Comment: Thanks @ThierryLathuille, what happens to 2 in `#2`, what does the interpreter do with it?

Comment: Nothing at all.

Comment: It ignores such parameter. The lambda redefines it, this is why we can change it's name and it still works